# Let $X, Y ∼ U[0, 1]$ and suppose that $X $ and $Y$ are independent.

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Let $X, Y ∼ U[0, 1]$ and suppose that $X $ and $Y$ are independent.

Find $P(X ≤ Y ≤ 2X)$

Any ideas on how to get this one started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P(X < Y < 2X) = \int_0^1\int_{y/2}^y \, dx \,dy = \frac{1}{4}$$

Note that the joint density is $0$ outside the unit square and

$$P(X < Y < 2X) \neq \int_0^1\int_{x}^{2x} \, dy \,dx $$

Comment: Indeed.  Specifically, if one did wish to explore that option then: $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X\leqslant Y \leqslant 2X) ~=~& \int_0^1\int_x^{\min \{1, 2x\}} 1\operatorname d y\operatorname d x \\[1ex] ~=~& \int_0^{1/2}\int_x^{2x}1\operatorname d y\operatorname d x + \int_{1/2}^1\int_x^1 1\operatorname d y\operatorname d x \end{align}$$ And so, the first approach *is* slightly easier.

Comment: @Graham Kemp: Yes - thanks.  I was merely pointing this out to refute a now deleted, misleading comment.

Answer (score 3):

Draw the part of the unit square $[0,1]^2$ that corresponds to this event. It's straightforward to find its area geometrically.